# upload data to geoserver with gxp upload panel

Tags: raster, geoserver

I installed geoserver in my computer. I use wampserver (php, apache), and when i use the   examble "layer-upload.html" then i have the erro 405:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

Answer (score 1):

finally  i found the answer! In order to be able to use the layer-upload.html, we have to use  geoserver from opengeosuite or geoserver 2.5 beta. The reason is that the method "import" used from this examble is avalaible only to this specific version of geoserver.